Cannot force video at 60fps with HQ camera and picamera2
I am using a pi 4B with 8GB RAM and bookworm OS and the pi HQ camera.
picamera2 returns sensor_mode[0] (below) that should support 60 fps video at 1332x990 image size.  If I set camera configuration to use this sensor mode with an image of 1332x990 output size, I still get a 30 fps video.  My question is how can I design a video configuration in picamera2 to support acquisition of a 60 fps video at 1332x990?
sensor_modes[0]
{'bit_depth': 10,
 'crop_limits': (696, 528, 2664, 1980),
 'exposure_limits': (31, 667234896, None),
 'format': SRGGB10_CSI2P,
 'fps': 120.05,
 'size': (1332, 990),
 'unpacked': 'SRGGB10'}

Example code to acquire a 60 fps video:
from picamera2 import Picamera2
from picamera2.encoders import H264Encoder
import time

picam2 = Picamera2()

# Create a video configuration with 1332x990 output size, and force the high framerate 
# sensor mode and force a 60 fps framerate

config = picam2.create_video_configuration(main={"size": (1332,990)},
                                           raw=picam2.sensor_mode[0],
                                          controls={"FrameDurationLimits": (16666,16666)})
# configure camera
picam2.configure(config)

# set encoder and output
encoder = H264Encoder(framerate=60) 
output = "picam2_60fps.h264"

# record a 10 sec video at 60 fps
picam2.set_controls({"FrameRate": 60}) # this was suggested by another SO post
picam2.start_recording(encoder=encoder,output=output)
sleep(10)
picam2.stop_recording()
picam2.close


Hi @jsotola i tried to make question more succinct.  thanks.

config looks fine; you could try reduce the resolution to something smaller to see if the hardware can actually capture 60fps. Alternatively, instead of using FrameDurationLimits you can use FrameRate, and set that to 60 in create_video_configuration
